# Join LINQ with a List<> in select new

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

hi first time im asking here so il try to do it correctly

i have a problem im making a shopping basket and im nearly there but always a but

what i want to have is something like this

```
List<HKurv> KurvInnhold = (List<HKurv>)Session["KurvInnhold"];
DataClasses1DataContext db = new DataClasses1DataContext();

if (Session["KurvInnhold"] != null)
        {
            var query = from a in db.Cabinets
                        from b in db.Commodities
                        from e in db.sArticleNumbers
                        from d in KurvInnhold

                        where
                        d.VareKjøpt.Contains(e.ArtNum) &&
                        a.ArticleNumberID == e.ID &&
                        a.ArticleNumberID == b.ArticleNumberID

                        select new
                        {
                            BestiltAntall = d.AntallValgt,
                            Price = b.Price,
                            ModelName = a.ModelName,
                        };

            Handlekurv1.DataSource = query;
            Handlekurv1.DataBind();
        }
```

But it does not allow for usage of db and list<> in same query

Solved! Modified magnus's answer

```
            var kjopKollonne = from p in KurvInnhold
                               select p.VareKjøpt;

            var query1 = (from a in db.Cabinets
                         from b in db.Commodities
                         from e in db.sArticleNumbers

                         where
                         kjopKollonne.Contains(e.ArtNum) &&
                         a.ArticleNumberID == e.ID &&
                         a.ArticleNumberID == b.ArticleNumberID
                        select new
                         {
                              ArtNum = e.ArtNum,
                              Price = b.Price,
                              ModelName = a.ModelName,
                         }).ToList();

            var query2 = from a in query1
                         join b in KurvInnhold on a.ArtNum equals b.VareKjøpt
                         select new
                         {
                              BestiltAntall = b.AntallValgt,
                              Price = a.Price,
                              ModelName = a.ModelName,
                         };

            Handlekurv1.DataSource = query2;
            Handlekurv1.DataBind();
```

Comment: "BestiltAntall" means "Nr Of Orders" right? Are you sure you dont need a count on the antall2 collection?

Comment: it means amount ordered of a specific item.
the numbers exists in debug locals, so i can see they exist i just cannot get them out to the gridview. and i really dont know how

Comment: "amount ordered" does sound like it should be an integer not a collection.
BestiltAntall is a child collection of the "query" collection, how do you intend to display it in the grid? You would need some kind of sub grid in the GridViewRows of the Handlekurv1 grid

Comment: updated the question think its easier to understand what i want to do

Comment: Ok, I think I understand what you want, check out my answer below. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var query1 = from a in db.Cabinets
  from b in db.Commodities
  from e in db.sArticleNumbers
  from d in KurvInnhold
  where
  KurvInnhold.Select(k => k.VareKjøpt).Contains(e.ArtNum) &&
  a.ArticleNumberID == e.ID &&
  a.ArticleNumberID == b.ArticleNumberID

 select new
  {
       ArtNum = e.ArtNum,
       Price = b.Price,
       ModelName = a.ModelName,
  }.ToList();

var query2 = 
  from a in query1
  join b in KurvInnhold on a.ArtNum equals b.VareKjøpt
  select new
  {
       BestiltAntall = b.AntallValgt,
       Price = a.Price,
       ModelName = a.ModelName,
  };

Handlekurv1.DataSource = query2;
Handlekurv1.DataBind();
```

Comment: returns same error as everytime i think im close Local sequence cannot be used in LINQ to SQL implementations of query operators except the Contains operator.

Comment: solved it by changing some things and adding a small part dont know if im to push solved on your post or not il let you decide, il put the answer in the main post ty

Comment: Only query1 runs in the DB and it only uses the list with the  Contains operator, so it should work... Are you sure you'r doing ToList() at the end of query1?